How to calculate builder's bribe in transaction?
On ethereum we can check state changes and get it for builders/miners. But how to know how much bribe wallet or address has submitted?
Let's take this example I downloaded directly from blockchain. This is the first transaction in block (index=0) https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf51d65a013913e1854536219cfe8e53c5898a1518428b600db9ff4e5f4fb3e51
tx=0xf51d65a013913e1854536219cfe8e53c5898a1518428b600db9ff4e5f4fb3e51, index=0, 0.0049s
 miner=0x4838b106fce9647bdf1e7877bf73ce8b0bad5f97 (Titan Builder) builder, diff=28742340000000000 (0.02874234 ETH), before=6.686884000673791132 ETH, after=6.715626340673791132 ETH
 gas=306978, gasPrice=242923009738 (242.923009738 Gwei)
 gasUsed=139886, cumulativeGasUsed=139886
 tx_fee=gasPrice*gasUsed=306978*242923009738=74572019683351764 (0.074572019683351764 ETH)
 maxFeePerGas=3333000000000 (3333.0 Gwei), maxPriorityFeePerGas=222000000000 (222.0 Gwei)
 baseFeePerGas=20923009738 (20.923009738 Gwei) => burned_fee=20923009738*21000=439383204498000 (0.000439383204498 ETH)
 diff - burned_fee=28302956795502000 (0.028302956795502 ETH)

We can see miner has received 0.02874234 ETH
Now, let's see the last one transaction with index=151:
tx=0xdf2022db104cf2ce41e5b037195be8873f559e1bf8dd04d4e88fa30f7bd6d2fc, index=151, 0.0019s
 miner=0x4838b106fce9647bdf1e7877bf73ce8b0bad5f97 (Titan Builder) builder, diff=21000000000000 (0.000021 ETH), before=6.686884000673791132 ETH, after=6.686905000673791132 ETH
 gas=21000, gasPrice=21923009738 (21.923009738 Gwei)
 gasUsed=21000, cumulativeGasUsed=12377721
 tx_fee=gasPrice*gasUsed=21000*21923009738=460383204498000 (0.000460383204498 ETH)
 maxFeePerGas=43953039022 (43.953039022 Gwei), maxPriorityFeePerGas=1000000000 (1.0 Gwei)
 baseFeePerGas=20923009738 (20.923009738 Gwei) => burned_fee=20923009738*21000=439383204498000 (0.000439383204498 ETH)
 diff - burned_fee=-418383204498000 (0.000418383204498 ETH)

Miner has received 0.000021 ETH
So how to know actually how much bribe was received on top block transactions? Is it simple 0.02874234 ETH - 0.000021 ETH for the first transaction? Should we consider burned fee?
